# Textview not autoresizing as expected in android

Tags: android, textview, autoresize

I have textview where i show some words in large size one by one.
When i move to next word, if that word is bigger it should resize automatically without going nextline or anything.
below is my textview code from xml.

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/word_content_numericaltext"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
     android:layout_toEndOf="@id/leftarrowword"
     android:layout_toStartOf="@id/rightarrowword"
     android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="180sp"
     android:autoSizeMinTextSize="80sp"
     android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
     android:fontFamily="@font/futurainfant_book"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:text="word"
     android:textAlignment="center"
     android:textColor="@color/paint_darkblue"
     android:textSize="180sp" />
```

when i move from a smaller word to bigger word , its working as expected .
But when move back to smaller word , the text get smaller .

[![small word large font][1]][1]

[![larger word autoresized as expected][2]][2]

[![moved back to smaller word but text is smaller than before][3]][3]

How do i solve this ?

small word large font
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBHov.png
larger word autoresized as expected
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/urneU.png
moved back to smaller word but text is smaller than before
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCodt.png

Answer (score 0):

With Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, you can instruct a TextView to let the text size expand or contract automatically to fill its layout based on the TextView's characteristics and boundaries. This setting makes it easier to optimize the text size on different screens with dynamic content.

**Note:  If you set autosizing in an XML file, it is not recommended to use the value "wrap_content" for the layout_width or layout_height attributes of a TextView. It may produce unexpected results.**

You should set your layout_height

```
 android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Refer here for more details : [autosizing_textview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview#setting-textview-autosize)